# Validating XML that doesn't define a schema using Xerces

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces

I'm using the Xerces-C++ (version 2.6.1) SAX2 parser to validate XML such as the document below.  (This is MSML - Media Server Markup Language as defined in [RFC 5707](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5707).)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msml version="1.1">
   <createconference name="example">
      <audiomix>
         <n-loudest n="3"/>
         <asn ri="10s"/>
      </audiomix>
   </createconference>
</msml>
```

The RFC provides [XML schemas for validating MSML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5707#section-16), and I'm trying to use them in conjunction with the Xerces SAX2 parser to validate and parse MSML.  The parsing is working fine, but I'm failing to get any validation.  I suspect my problem might be because the MSML I'm trying to validate doesn't include a `schemaLocation` attribute, but I can't control what XML I receive - I would like to force validation using the msml.xsd whether `schemaLocation` or `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` (or nothing) is provided in the XML.

My code is similar to the following.

```
SAX2XMLReader* parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();

// Enable the parser's schema support 
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgXercesSchema, true);

// Schema validation requires namespace processing to be turned on.
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgSAX2CoreValidation, true);
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgSAX2CoreNameSpaces, true);

// Define the location of the MSML schema.
XMLCh* schemaLocation = XMLString::transcode("/directory/path/msml-core.xsd");
parser->setProperty(XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaExternalNoNameSpaceSchemaLocation,
                    schemaLocation);

// MSMLHandler is defined elsewhere and inherits from xercesc/sax2/DefaultHandler
// It overrides startElement and fatalError.
MxMSMLHandler* msmlHandler = new MSMLHandler(xiSessionID, xoMSMLResponse);
parser->setContentHandler((ContentHandler*) msmlHandler);
parser->setErrorHandler((ErrorHandler*) msmlHandler);

// Do the parse
parser->parse(*xmlInputSource);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And with much flailing around and trial and error, I eventually found the problems.  Validation errors are reported to the `error` callback on the `ErrorHandler` passed to the parser.  There was no problem with the `schemaLocation` attribute.

With that fixed, and adding in caching of the XML grammar to improve performance, the code is now as follows.

```
SAX2XMLReader* parser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();

// Enable the parser's schema support 
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgXercesSchema, true);

// Schema validation requires namespace processing to be turned on.
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgSAX2CoreValidation, true);
parser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgSAX2CoreNameSpaces, true);

// Cache the XML grammar and use it for subsequent parses.
mParser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgXercesCacheGrammarFromParse, true);
mParser->setFeature(XMLUni::fgXercesUseCachedGrammarInParse, true);

// Define the location of the MSML schema.
XMLCh* schemaLocation = XMLString::transcode("/directory/path/msml-core.xsd");
parser->setProperty(XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaExternalNoNameSpaceSchemaLocation,
                    schemaLocation);

// MSMLHandler is defined elsewhere and inherits from xercesc/sax2/DefaultHandler
// It overrides startElement, fatalError *and error*.
MxMSMLHandler* msmlHandler = new MSMLHandler(xiSessionID, xoMSMLResponse);
parser->setContentHandler((ContentHandler*) msmlHandler);
parser->setErrorHandler((ErrorHandler*) msmlHandler);

// Do the parse
parser->parse(*xmlInputSource);
```